# Incompatible provider version with terraform-providers/mysql

Tags: mysql, terraform

I'm reinitializing the terraform which state is located in gitlab. And I'm getting such an error:

```
Error: Incompatible provider version
│ 
│ Provider registry.terraform.io/terraform-providers/mysql v1.9.0 does not have a package available for your current platform, darwin_arm64.
│ 
│ Provider releases are separate from Terraform CLI releases, so not all providers are available for all platforms. Other versions of this
│ provider may have different platforms supported.
```

I guess it's because I use MAC M1.
Here is how my configuration looks like:

```
required_providers {
  mysql = {
     source  = "terraform-providers/mysql"
     version = "~> 1.9.0"
}
}
```

I tried to change the source to the "petaju/mysql" but still getting the same error. Also before that moved "terraform.lock.hcl" to another folder. I just need to successfully initialize terraform and no matter will it require to change the source of the mysql provider

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that.

Comment: @MarkoE it's not possible at all?

Comment: Well, you could in theory create a Linux VM on your Mac, but not sure if that would help considering the CPU architecture.

Comment: You would need to reach out to the provider maintainers and request they release a binary linked for ARM architecture. You could also download the provider source and build the binary yourself locally, and then install the output artifact locally. That would be really annoying to maintain though.

Comment: @MarkoE Yeah actually We finally decided to do everything on Docker container

Comment: @devopsengineer Is this issue fixed? or are you using docker container